# MATLAB convert graythresh output into actual intensity

Tags: matlab, image-thresholding

I am trying to find the threshold of a 3D image that is 258 x 318 x 801 double. I first reshaped the image into 1D array and then used graythresh

```
ROI = reshape(postImg,[],1);
thresh = graythresh(ROI);
```

But I was trying to find the actually intensity threshold instead of a value between 0 and 1. Is there a way to convert this other than using multithresh?

Comment: What does "actually intensity threshold" mean if not "a value between 0 and 1"? What value do you expect?

Comment: I am expecting a value ranging from 1000 -100000. some value like that

Comment: Why are you expecting that? Can you provide a *small* sample image and your expected threshold? I still don't understand what you're calling the "actual intensity threshold".

Comment: I actually figured that that.. I just need to de-normalize the value

Comment: Cool, but just for my curiosity I'd like to know what kind of image has an intensity value from 1000 - 100000. Intensity values normally range from 0-1 for floating-point or 0-255 for uint8 images.

Comment: it is a ct scanned image of a bone (with tissue and vessels). The vessels part has a intensity value around  >=7000, and the edge of the bone has a intensity value around 2000~.. and then it gets lower as it moves out of the bone to the empty space

Comment: Oh, cool. Yeah, definitely not normal image numbers ;)

Answer (score 1):

From [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html#bvhttkq-I):

> The graythresh function converts multidimensional arrays to 2-D
>   arrays, using reshape, and ignores any nonzero imaginary part of I.

So, your reshape is probably redundant. I think this would do:

```
thresh = graythresh(postImg); % postIm can be 3D
BinIm = imbinarize(postIm,thresh); % creates a binary mask of your image
```